# Query DynamoDB by column using DynamoDBMapper

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

Im using loacalstack with dynamodb setup. Iv a table with two columns, an Id and a name column. Im struggling to query the table by 'name' using DynamoDBMapper. Below is a snippet of my setup

entity >

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "my-table")
public class Table {

   private String id;
   private String name;

   @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
   @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   @DynamoDBAttribute
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
```

@query >

```
public Table getByName(String name) {  
   return dynamoDBMapper.load(Table.class, name);
}
```

```
aws dynamodb create-table --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4569 --table-name my-table \
          --attribute-definitions AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S AttributeName=name,AttributeType=S \
          --key-schema AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=name,KeyType=RANGE \
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you cannot query the table by name as it is not the partition/hash key. Either you can use scan or you should state `name` as a GSI field and then query it. Scan command would be like:

```
dynamoDBMapper.scan(Table.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression());
```

The above command will scan the entire table. Read about DynamoDBScanExpression [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.QueryScanExample.html) to see how you can filter it with a specific `name`.

You can add a filter like on `name` like:

```
public Table getByName(String name) {  
    DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
    scanExpression.addFilterCondition("name", new Condition()                                           
       .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)                                                
       .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(name)));
    dynamoDBMapper.scan(Table.class, scanExpression);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, works like a charm :) . It does state to use query over scan when possible. Is it a case of switching DynamoDBScanExpression for DynamoDBQueryExpression

Comment: @rogger2016: Hi. I am not sure if DynamoDBQueryExpression works here as this is a scan operation. You can try and let me know.. I usually use DynamoDBQueryExpression when I am doing dynamoDBMapper.query(). Thanks!

Comment: @rogger2016 can you do an example of this code using DynamoDBQueryExpression, please :)

Comment: Do up a question and Ill add an answer :)